# Is there any implementation of database by perl

Tags: database, perl, perl-module, dbi, dbd

Is there any perl modules implementing function of database and easy to use. I do not need modules used to connect to some database products. I need simple database writing by perl.

Thanks.

Comment: If what you want is to store data in your hdd, you can use `DBM::Deep`, it is easy to manage

Comment: Does this module support query like SQL?

Comment: [DBD::SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite) is a self-contained database management system fully compatible with the standard [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) module.

Comment: You might also like [DBD::CSV](http://p3rl.org/DBD::CSV) which provides a standard SQL interface to CSV files.

Comment: You can use JSON, XML, YAMS formats to store data. Depending on chosen structure of the database you can implement  utility functions. Otherwise you can look at DBM 
 - https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::DBM.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would suggest using [DBD::SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite). This is a self-contained database management system with no dependency to external binaries (unlike most others DBI drivers). It has nice options such as creating in-memory databases.

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) is an open-source RDBMS that implements a significant subset of the SQL ANSI Standard.

`DBD::SQLite` is a legitimate DBI driver, so it conforms to the API of the great [DBI module](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI), which is the de-facto Perl standard interface for databases.

From the documentation:

> DBD::SQLite is a Perl DBI driver for SQLite, that includes the entire thing in the distribution. So in order to get a fast transaction capable RDBMS working for your perl project you simply have to install this module, and **nothing** else.

Comment: "_with no dependency to external binaries_"  -- well, you need the actual sqlite  library itself (C). While that gets installed by the package, the Perl thing (DBD::SQLite) is just a driver. I second the suggestion, but it sure has a "dependency."

Comment: @zdim it's not an external binary (it's linked in directly, not "installed" separately, and there's no server), and it's not a "dependency" in the sense of a prerequisite that you need to get beforehand or separately. So I think the answer gives a fair assessment.

Comment: @hobbs Dunno ... it's an independent general C library that the Perl bit interfaces. Even if the package bundles an sqlite version for convenience that is still a separate pop of C code, no-relation-to-Perl.  This is mostly semantics, and I support the answer (and upvoted it), but to my mind this is exactly a Perl driver for an external library.

Answer (score 3):

If you can live without SQL and relations, give [DBM::Deep](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBM-Deep/lib/DBM/Deep.pod) a try. Easiest of all, I wouldn't use it in production environment for sure, but it is ideal for rapid prototyping.

> DESCRIPTION
>
> A unique flat-file database module, written in pure perl. True multi-level hash/array support (unlike MLDBM, which is faked), hybrid OO / tie() interface, cross-platform FTPable files, ACID transactions, and is quite fast. Can handle millions of keys and unlimited levels without significant slow-down. Written from the ground-up in pure perl -- this is NOT a wrapper around a C-based DBM. Out-of-the-box compatibility with Unix, Mac OS X and Windows.

Comment: I would take a try